# C# Generic types GetProperties() returns 0 properties

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following code which i would expect to return the properties within the generic type.

```
   var newType = new T();
            Type t = newType.GetType();
            var prop = t.GetProperties();
```

prop has 0 properties and i cant understand why, when inspecting the type object at debug it is showing the correct object. The object im using as the generic.

```
public class SOPOH
{

    public String OHDELF { get; set; }

    public Decimal OHORDR { get; set; }

    public String OHSTAT { get; set; }

    public String OHSUSP { get; set; }

    public Decimal OHODDT { get; set; }

    public String OHCUSN { get; set; }

    public String OHCSUB { get; set; }
}
```

prop returns `{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]}`

t returns `{Name = "SOPOH" FullName = "AS400_Library.Repositorys.CHGDGADV.SOPOH"}`

The Generic class:

```
     public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : new()
    {

        public List<T> GetAll(Settings settings)
        {
            var returned = new List<T>();

            var newType = new T();
            Type t = newType.GetType();
            var prop = t.GetProperties();

            Console.WriteLine(prop.Length);


            return returned;

        }
}
```

The Interface:

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : new()
{
    List<T> GetAll(Settings settings);
}
```

The implementation of the repository:

```
 public class SOPOH : Repository<SOPOH>
{

    public SOPOH()
    {
    }

}
```

The call to the code:

```
  var t = new AS400_Library.Repositorys.CHGDGADV.SOPOH();
        var values = t.GetAll(new Settings());
```

Comment: Put the declaration code of your generic function or class here

Comment: Your initial code is a complicated way of writing `typeof(T).GetProperties()`, though that should not change the results.

Comment: Without generic your code works as expected. So the problem maybe is in the generic part you haven't posted

Comment: @ Ben +1, plz share your T Class code

Comment: @Ferus7 What should I share? I've just replaced T with SOPOH and got all properties :) Thats's what I meant with "without generic"

Comment: @ Ben, i said that to @Houlahan, +1 means that i agree with you

Comment: Your code works with the generic too. I put your code in `public void GetProperties<T>() where T : new()` and called `GetProperties<SOPOH>()` and it returned me the same property list as `typeof(SOPOH).GetProperties()`...

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the [..] the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ) - we cannot reproduce your problem with the code in the question which makes this question off topic. We'd love to help so just provide a minimal complete and verifiable example to demonstrate your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more on what that means.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the T class and its interface.

Comment: You must post a [mcve], the code as it stands works, there must be a bug in code you haven't posted.

Comment: Added the implementation of the repository class and the call off the repository.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you have two *different* classes called `SOPOH`, one of which is a `Repository<>` of the other? If that's so, are you sure the one you're scanning for properties is the one you *think* you are scanning for properties? How about **actually creating** a [mcve], rather than a pile of snippets for us to piece together?

Comment: What a school boy error, i was referencing the incorrect version of SOPOH. Was referencing the repository instead of the model.